# Error after second try to register 

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am using custom asp.net membership in MVC 3.0

Registration working well without problems, but during testing i found one issue
If i put incorrect value for example password which is not meet asp.net membership settings criteria then i get server validation error saying that i need to fix:

```
Your account wasn't created. Please correct the errors and try again. 
The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.
```

So then if put another password and clicking submit i am getting this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 
 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 


Stack Trace: 

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Decode(String encodedData, MachineKeyProtection protectionOption) +269
   Microsoft.Web.Mvc.MachineKeyWrapper.Decode(String encodedData, MachineKeyProtection protectionOption) +10
   Microsoft.Web.Mvc.MvcSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedValue, SerializationMode mode, IMachineKey machineKey) +80

[SerializationException: Deserialization failed. Verify that the data is being deserialized using the same SerializationMode with which it was serialized. Otherwise see the inner exception.]
   Microsoft.Web.Mvc.MvcSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedValue, SerializationMode mode, IMachineKey machineKey) +232
   Microsoft.Web.Mvc.MvcSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedValue, SerializationMode mode) +25
   Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DeserializingModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +128

.....
```

any ideas what it could be?

my controller looking like that:

```
public virtual ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model, [Deserialize]List<MyModelState> myModelState)
{
  //to stuff
  //if error save ModelStt in temp data to render it back to hidden form value
  TempData["MyModelState"] = myModelState;
}
```

On the view i am doing this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    List<MyModelState> hidden = TempData["MyModelState"] as List<MyModelState>;

    if (hidden != null) //never null 
    {        
        @Html.Serialize("MyModelState", hidden)
    } 
}
```

I think the problem with `[Deserialize]List<MyModelState>`  but i cant understand why it may heppend because the hidden value represented that object never null and always present in the form:

```
<input name="MyModelState" type="hidden" value="2CF80623577311BA401E41727261794F66537562736372697074696F6E44657461...../>
```

I check the value of `MyModelState` in the form before error it happends and when it happends i click browser button back to make sure that hidden value is there in form and equal to value which it was before error and it is all right, couldn't see something bad there.

Comment: are you using shared hosting?

Answer (score 0):

I encounted same exception.

I changed web.config, sessionState mode, from "InProc" to "StateServer".

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" .../>
    ...
```

(of course, session state mode not must be "SateServer", you can chose "SQLServer", or "Custom".)

Then, it look like fixed.

Please try.